# How do I get collapse in Twitter Bootstrap to work here

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HI THERE</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class = "container">
                <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">ABC</a>
                <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                    BUTTON
                </button>   
                <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href ="#">home</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src = "http//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here's my code for making a basic responsive collapsing Navbar using twitter bootstrap. I'm calling the button "BUTTON", and I'd like it to be visible when the screen is compressed. When I click on this button, I'd like a drop down with the "Home" link, and some others, when I add them in later. For some reason, the button isn't cascading when I compress my screen. I only see the button, but when I click on it, it doesn't expand!

P.S - I am guessing this is pretty basic stuff for a lot of coders on this website, but If you'd like me to add comment entries in to the code to make clear my intent line by line, just let me know and I will be happy to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you have to jquery is not correct. You are missing the : after http.

As in, it should read:

```
<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

One important thing to check before you start working on functionality is to ensure all your css and jquery files are included properly. You can do this by opening the console in your browser, if any external resources fail to load, there will be an error regarding this.

Best of luck.

Comment: The other answer by Steve H works because jquery is being included earlier in the file, which is different to how your file is set up.

Comment: Thank you! I'd never have caught that, but I'll be sure to check this the next time onward.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine with no issues, other than the color of the button.  Take a look at this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/uyEYUMo/3/edit

Comment: Thanks for the help, I see it's working on the link you sent me. Is there any reason it should't work when I open the html document using Chrome?

Comment: Are you sure your version of Bootstrap is the correct version and being loaded properly?  In the JSBin, I loaded the "latest" bootstrap and it worked fine, since you did not post "css/bootstrap.min.css".

Comment: As Paul Haggo mentions, your URL is incorrect for jquery.  When I added Bootstrap via JSBin, it also included the correct jQuery.

Comment: Looks like my http was missing a ":". SMH. Thanks!